# Get UNIX server monthly bandwidth usage with PHP

Tags: php, linux, unix

Is there anyway i can get the servers monthly bandwidth usage using php ?
Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your best bet is to parse number of packets that passed ethX inteface
command that keeps track of bytes passed is /sbin/ifconfig
Keep in mind that counters are reset if you reboot your linux box

```
eth0      
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:32363649 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35133219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2813232645 (2.6 GiB)  TX bytes:1696525681 (1.5 GiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f4000000-f4012700
```

Comment: the reboot would be a problem , not effective , will have errors for sure !

Comment: if the value read is smaller than the value before , means a reboot occured , then just add it to the last saved value + some error margin (wich would be average bandwidth-per-hour * hours since last check  ... will need some workout , but it'sa nice idea ... any way to do it through windows ?

Comment: Long time linux sysadmin here, so sorry no windows solution :) I guess windows also logs traffic counters somewhere, after all its showed on network interface status

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your site's apache access log to figure out the total bandwidth. Here's a loose pseudo-php example (the actual implementation will depend on your log format):

```
<?php
$logfile = '/var/log/apache/httpd-access.log';
$startDate = '2010-10-01';
$endDate = '2010-10-31';

$fh = fopen($logfile, 'r');

if (!$fh) die('Couldn\'t open log file.');

$totalBytes = 0;

// let's pretend the log is a csv file because i'm lazy at parsing
while (($info = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ' ', '"')) !== false) {
  // get the date of the log entry
  $date = $info[3];
  // check if the date is within our month of interest
  if ($date > $startDate && $date < $endDate) {
    // get the number of bytes sent in the request
    $totalBytes += $info[7];
  }
}

fclose($fh);

echo 'Total bytes used: ' . $totalBytes;
```

Also, this script is likely to be very slow depending on size of your logs, so you should considering caching the result for later use instead of running it repeatedly.

Comment: In that case, consider setting up AWStats or similar software which is meant for log file analysis/statistics, have it keep itself updated regularly (through a cronjob), and then parse AWStats' data cache files.